Upload an Image and have the title name using openai package in R
I am trying to upload an image and have the title description using the openAI packgae in R
library(openai)
Sys.setenv(OPENAI_API_KEY = "myopenAIkey")   
image_path <- 'www/img/book1.jpg'


create_chat_completion( model = 'gpt-4o',
                        messages = list(
                          list(
                            role = "user",
                            # - - - - - - - 
                            content = list(
                              list(
                                type = "text",
                                text = "What’s in this image?"
                              ),
                              list(
                                type = "image_url",
                                image_url = list(
                                  url = 'book1.jpg',
                                  detail = "high"
                                )
                              )
                            )
                            # - - - - - - - 
                          )
                        )
                        )

This is the error that I have:
Erro: OpenAI API request failed [400]:

Invalid image.

But its not working
Should I have to use this output into other function?
Any help guys?

The image needs to be 64-bit encoded before you send it to gpt. I can post the Python code that I use for this to give you a starting point if you like - but I don't know R.


install and load the RCurl package 2) Read image to raw vector img_raw <- readBin(image_path, what = "raw", n = file.info(image_path)$size) 3) Encode the raw vector to a base64 img64 <- base64Encode(img_raw, "image/jpeg") 4) send img64 object to ChatGPT. Let me know if this works and I will post it as an answer.

